# Add items to vector with two strings

Tags: java, vector

I have created to strings.

```
public class Program
{
    private String code;
    private String name;

    public Program(String theCode, String theName)
    {
        code = theCode;
        name = theName;
    }
}
```

Now I want to add some items into a vector of type Program.

```
public class ProgramList
{
    private Vector<Program> list;

    public ProgramList()
    {
    list = new Vector<Program>();
    }
```

Then, in the same class, I read two strings from each line of text in the .txt file. The strings are separated by two whitespaces.

```
    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader
                           (new FileReader("programs.txt"));
    String line;
    int i = 0;
    while ((line = infile.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String c, n;
        StringTokenizer linesplit = new StringTokenizer(line, "  ");
        c = linesplit.nextElement().toString();
        n = linesplit.nextElement().toString();
        list.add(???);
        i++;
    }  
}
```

How can I add the string c and n to the vector list? How could I use list.add();?

Comment: Why use `Vector` in 2014? I am frankly amazed that the JDK _still_ doesn't mark it as `@Deprecated`... Use a `List` instead

Comment: Vector might be useful in multithreaded applications, couldn't it? Lists are not synchronized.

Comment: @Joffrey you forget about `CopyOnWriteArrayList`; being synchronized is one thing, being concurrent-friendly, however, is another ;)

Comment: Vector are synchronized by default and then are a lot slower. If you need a thread safe list, there's also a way to get it.

Comment: @Joffrey If you absolutely need a synchronized collection class, then use `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` to wrap a `List` with synchronization. Don't use the legacy `Vector` collection class.

Comment: Well that's true, I never use `Vector` anyway. When I need thread-safe operations, they are rarely on the list itself only. In most cases, the list is part of a bigger object that does synchronized stuff around the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is just on the adding statement, you can write this:

```
list.add(new Program(c, n));
```

This way, you create a `Program` object containing the strings. And this object is added to the list.

Comment: It's declared in the constructor? This worked, thanks.

Comment: Right, my mistake, I didn't see it was the same class :)

Answer (score 0):

Add them by creating a new Object of `Program`. Replace your last code part with the following

**The code:**

```
    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader
                       (new FileReader("programs.txt"));
String line;
int i = 0;
while ((line = infile.readLine()) != null)
{
    String c, n;
    StringTokenizer linesplit = new StringTokenizer(line, "  ");
    c = linesplit.nextElement().toString();
    n = linesplit.nextElement().toString();
    list.add(new Program(c,n));
    i++;
}  
}
```

**Recommendation:** use `ArrayList` instead of Vector. It is easier to deal with more than `Vector` and provided by a lot of other features. Read this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm) for more info about `ArrayList`